# Json multiple arrays in one string

Tags: json

Im trying to read a json stream. Need to list all the titles. Not sure what is up with the format of this stream tho, it looks like there are multiple arrays in one json stream. How do i pull out all the titles and make one list.

This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<script>
const data = 
'{"published_at":"2018-07-01","title":"Lorem & ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit","_kw":[]}';
const obj2 = JSON.parse(data);
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = obj2.title;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

This does not:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo2"></p>
<script>
const data = 
'{"published_at":"2018-07-01","title":"Lorem & ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2019-07-02","title":"Vestibulum in arcu neque. Pellentesque feugiat, mauris at congue semper. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2017-07-03","title":"Nulla iaculis, massa sit amet tempor pellentesque, sem ligula euismod metus, eget blandit tortor arcu eu nisl","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2018-06-01","title":"Pellentesque non feugiat ante. Donec dignissim turpis id orci consectetur. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2014-09-02","title":"Aliquam convallis turpis urna, ut dapibus arcu faucibus interdum","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2017-12-03","title":"Duis id elit eu metus commodo volutpat at at velit. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2018-01-01","title":"Aliquam tristique dui turpis, nec facilisis tellus eleifend id. Morbi. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2019-05-02","title":"Nam arcu mauris, porttitor ut leo id, luctus malesuada orci. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2017-07-03","title":"Donec ut mi bibendum, pharetra dolor sed, dapibus mauris. In. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2015-01-01","title":"Morbi enim metus, mollis in ultrices molestie, sagittis quis elit. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2017-02-02","title":"Curabitur vestibulum lorem in ex semper iaculis. Mauris vel facilisis. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2015-03-22","title":"Donec interdum nibh blandit bibendum hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2016-06-19","title":"Etiam ac tellus quis felis cursus vulputate. Maecenas at felis. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2019-04-30","title":"Integer mi sapien, pharetra at nunc vel, tristique sollicitudin augue. ","_kw":[]}';
const obj2 = JSON.parse(data);
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = obj2.title;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I can get it to list one title but not all of them. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to correct your JSON string. If this is a object array you need to write it as an array. Add square brackets to your string.

```
const data = `[{"published_at":"2018-07-01","title":"Lorem & ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2019-07-02","title":"Vestibulum in arcu neque. Pellentesque feugiat, mauris at congue semper. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2017-07-03","title":"Nulla iaculis, massa sit amet tempor pellentesque, sem ligula euismod metus, eget blandit tortor arcu eu nisl","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2018-06-01","title":"Pellentesque non feugiat ante. Donec dignissim turpis id orci consectetur. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2014-09-02","title":"Aliquam convallis turpis urna, ut dapibus arcu faucibus interdum","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2017-12-03","title":"Duis id elit eu metus commodo volutpat at at velit. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2018-01-01","title":"Aliquam tristique dui turpis, nec facilisis tellus eleifend id. Morbi. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2019-05-02","title":"Nam arcu mauris, porttitor ut leo id, luctus malesuada orci. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2017-07-03","title":"Donec ut mi bibendum, pharetra dolor sed, dapibus mauris. In. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2015-01-01","title":"Morbi enim metus, mollis in ultrices molestie, sagittis quis elit. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2017-02-02","title":"Curabitur vestibulum lorem in ex semper iaculis. Mauris vel facilisis. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2015-03-22","title":"Donec interdum nibh blandit bibendum hendrerit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2016-06-19","title":"Etiam ac tellus quis felis cursus vulputate. Maecenas at felis. ","_kw":[]},{"published_at":"2019-04-30","title":"Integer mi sapien, pharetra at nunc vel, tristique sollicitudin augue. ","_kw":[]}] `
```

After that you can parse the string into JSON and it will give you an array of objects.

Comment: I did like you suggested but "undefined" gets sent to the screen.